# Reset all elements in javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening, I make a game in javascript in a one-page configuration (so I display/hide different div using jQuery & Ajax) and I've a little problem to reset a level.

When I select a level in the selection screen, it return the right level by displaying the div and launching the main javascript file :

```
    // Lancement du jeu 
    launchGame = true; 
    $("body").append('<script src="../src/main.js" id="startLevel"></script>');
```

And when I exit the level, I want the level to reset, so then I can re-launch it from the beginning :

```
$("#returnSelect").click(function() {

    // Destruction du level en cours 
    launchGame = false;
    destroy();
    $("#startLevel").remove();
});
```

The jquery remove function have to delete the main js file of the game from the document. The destroy function in this js file will reset all objects but the player object keep its x and y properties and the position remain the same :

```
// Destruction des objets 
$("#tileset").empty();
player = null;
```

However, I delete it, and I'm affraid to have deleting all of its properties one by one.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I would use an Object  to keep all of your settings, then create a `new` instance of it so you don't change the original Object. Just refer to the original Object when you want to do a reset. `if(!Object.create){Object.create = function(o){ function F(){}; F.prototype = o; return new F;}}`.

Comment: Thanks, that'll must be a good solution. I will try it !